# Reduce lag of PlatformView on flutter android

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

How to reduce the lag of PlatformView while scrolling? I know PlatformView's are heavy and in the doc they say what to do about it but there isn't doc about how to do it here is what the doc says about performance and here is a video of lag. I used ExoPlayer on the PlatformView

[image]

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/421445316617961502/1017783300305195080/scrcpy_CnRrZxRkjC.mp4